# Pycharm change Identifier Name where ever it has been used automatically if i change it where it has been defined

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am using Pycharm professional edition for my Python and Django project.

Is there anything in pycharm so that whenever i change the Varibale name/Function name/class name where it has been defined in the middle of my project. It will automatically changes the name wherever it has been referenced in a project with multiple files.

So that i dont have to check manually where it is used and change it accordingly.

Any suggestion please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click -> `refactor` -> `rename`

Then you get a dialog that will preview the changes for you.

Very slick.

Comment: Or use hotkey shift+F6. Most of hotkeys in `Help` -> `Default keymap reference`